# get contact from Kik Messenger

Tags: android, kik

I have application that send message from [Kik Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kik.android). I want to get contact that save in Kik Messanger. How can I get this contact list in my application. I want to send message to selected contact from my application using Kik Messenger.

Please help me for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application cannot get access to all the contacts saved by the messenger. However, you can ask the user to pick contacts that they are willing to send the message to. Kik's user picker is documented here: http://dev.kik.com/docs/#social-picker